# Trying to make a Header Background image appear on certain pages

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to add some css to portfolio pages only on my word press site.
An example page is:
http://www.1aproductions.co.uk/portfolio/22/

The css code i am trying to add is:

```
.header-wrapper {
background-position:top;
background-color:transparent !important;
background-image:url('http://www.1aproductions.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Florence-Nightingale-smaller-no-flo.jpg') !important;
background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Which would display a similar effect to the header on this page (if I could only get it to work!)
http://www.1aproductions.co.uk/work/?cat=dramas

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks
P

Comment: What is 'portfolio'? Is it a category? A custom post type? A taxonomy...?

Comment: Hi - I'm not sure exactly which of those it is! Looks like it could be a custom post type. (the theme has placed a new link on the left bar of the dashboard, that has a drawing pin icon) Each portfolio item is made and listed there, and there is a php doc called single-portfolio.php. I hope that answers your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though portfolio is a custom post type. So try this:

```
function my_custom_css() {
    if ( is_singular( 'portfolio' ) ) {
        echo "<style>
            .header-wrapper {
                background-position:top;
                background-color:transparent !important;
                background-image:url('http://www.1aproductions.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Florence-Nightingale-smaller-no-flo.jpg') !important;
                background-size: 100% auto;
            }
        </style>";
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_custom_css' );
```

Comment: Thanks - where should I add this? (sorry! I'm relatively new to wordpress!)

Comment: You'd add this to your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: Incredible! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

See the classes of body

single single-portfolio postid-22 siteorigin-panels fixed-header no-slider dark-header --- on portfolio

page page-id-7 page-template page-template-template-portfolio-gallery-php siteorigin-panels fixed-header no-slider dark-header --- on categories.

You can add your specific background using that classes.

```
.single-portfolio .header wrapper{
    background: xxx;
}
```

and

```
.page-id-7 .header wrapper{
    background: yyy;
}
```

Comment: I like the your approach (using the `body_class`) better than mine (`wp_head` hook) because it avoids the need for adding stuff to the `<head>`

Comment: Unfortunately - I couldn't get it to work though.single-portfolio - adding my css code within those 2 classes (adding it to the custom css section within the theme).